# PHP PDO search Issue using multiple input fields with LIKE statment giving all results even if 1 param given

Tags: php, forms, search, input, pdo

I'll try to show my search form and continue on bits of public method code.

Here's my form (basic):

```
<form action="" method="get">
        Name:<input type="text" name="name">
            Last Name:<input type="text" name="last_name">
            Age:<input type="text" name="age">
            <input type="submit" value="search" name="search">
        </form>
```

Moving on to my get method:

```
public function get($table){
        $ssql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE `name` LIKE :name || `last_name` LIKE :last_name';
        $name = '%'.$_GET['name'].'%';
        $last_name = '%'.$_GET['last_name'].'%';
        $stm = $this->dbh->prepare($ssql);
        $stm->bindParam(':name',$name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stm->bindParam(':last_name',$last_name,PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stm->execute();

        echo $stm->rowCount();

        while($result = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        echo $result->name.' '.$result->last_name.'<br>';

        }
        }
```

Basically this should give me results based on my `$_GET` form fields. My problem is that if I enter name "juris" it does not outputs only 3 rows of juris which are in database but all fields from database. But if I enter lastname and then submit it, it gives out only juris records but then ignores lastname search term.

Shouldn't query like "WHERE etc LIKE "term1" OR etc LIKE "term2" give out results based on OR between 2 given variables? It should separate results if one variable `$_get['value']` is given and others are empty?

Got it to work as intended but maybe some one could give a bit cleaner answer how to separate "%%" this wild card?

```
$ssql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE (`name` LIKE :name) || (`last_name` LIKE :last_name)';
        if(empty($_GET['name'])){
        $name = "";
        }else {
        $name = '%'.$_GET['name'].'%';
        }
        if(empty($_GET['last_name'])){
        $last_name = "";
        }else{
        $last_name = '%'.$_GET['last_name'].'%';
        }
```

used if statement to separate %% wildcard.

Comment: Your get() method is bad. It shouldn't be aware of `$_GET`, it should not echo anything, but return a value instead

Comment: then how should be formed - im new to this. i have gotten so far by learning myself and figuring it out. so its my first time asking help.

Comment: What you're doing here is a bad practice called **Tight-coupling**. Google for that

Answer (score 1):

You need to use parenthesis to group the two field comparisons like this:

```
SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE (`name` LIKE :name && :name_prov = 1) || (`last_name` LIKE :last_name && :last_name_prov = 1)
```

Comment: What is `name_prov` and `last_name_prov`? I can't see them in the original question.

Comment: i tryed some solution from here but then figured out i need to create properties for it so forgot to delete the unneeded code. so sorry for that. Edited Original post to match my current code.

Comment: Ok, I copied this from the previous edit so my answer doesn't match the new code.

Comment: so ok still trying to figure out, no success. it gives me results but only if i provide both fields. hmm. maybe there is something related to my url: http://localhost/ind/?name=juris&last_name=&age=&search=search

Comment: @DaveMorrissey tryed to use parenthesis - still does not work as it should.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE name LIKE "%%" OR last_name LIKE "%klava%" used this query in phpmyadmin sql window. so seems my query is giving a first variable a wildcard %% which results to show all fields. So question now is how do i seperate this wildcard if one of variables is empty?

Answer (score 0):

So yesterday i tryed to figure out how could i separate "%%" wildcard from SQL query.
My answer for this problem is to check if fields are empty, then change $variable to empty string. If not, use it with $_GET method and wrapping it with "%%" wildcard. To get desired result using query with LIKE statement.